# Script not running correctly on startup

Tags: bash, startup, raspbian, init.d

I have a very simple script that echoes some stuff then starts a VNC Server. It works fine when I run it on the command line but when it runs on startup it gives some strange results. Here is my script

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vncboot
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start VNC Server at boot time
# Description: Start VNC Server at boot time.
### END INIT INFO

#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/vncboot

USER=root
HOME=/root

export USER HOME

case "$1" in
 start)
  echo -e "[ \e[32mok\e[39m ] Starting VNC Server"
  #Insert your favoured settings for a VNC session
  /usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 &> /dev/null
  ;;

 stop)
  echo -e "[ \e[32mok\e[39m ] Stopping VNC Server"
 /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 &> /dev/null
 ;;

 *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vncboot {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

First of the echo doesn't run right. It gives me this,

```
-e [ \e[32mok\e[39m ] Starting VNC Server
```

Then the VNC Server works fine but it still displays the ouptut even though I don't wan't it to. This is the same for both start) and stop) cases.

Comment: What actual shell is `/bin/sh`? not all shells support the `&>` redirection syntax, you may need to use POSIX-compatible `> /dev/null 2>&1` instead. Similarly, the shell may be invoking a built-in `echo` which might not support `-e` and/or the ANSI escapes (although `/bin/echo` might).

Comment: works perfectly in "bash".

Comment: steeldriver thank you it works like a charm!!!

Comment: Please read the help tour. On this site answered are accepted and never marked with [SOLVED] and thanks and other chit-chat should be avoided in questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @steeldriver I figured it out. I changed,

```
command &> /dev/null
```

to,

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I also changed,

```
echo
```

to,

```
/bin/echo
```